# How can I improve my site security? Ajax requests with token?

Tags: php

I think I need to improve my site security where I have bunch of ajax requests.

Until now I used SESSION variables to log-in a user. Example of my login page:

**login.php**

```
/// START SECURE SESSION
function startSession($lifetime, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly)
{
    session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
    session_start();
}
// Initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    startSession(0, '/', 'example.com', true, true);
}
// Check if the user is already logged in
if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] == true || !empty($_SESSION["username"])) {
    header("location: https://example.com/admin/");
    exit;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// Check if username is empty
    if (empty(trim($_POST["username"]))) {
        $username_err = "Username field is empty.";
    } else {
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }
    
    // Check if password is empty
    if (empty(trim($_POST["password"]))) {
        $password_err = "Password field is empty.";
    } else {
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
if (empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)) {
            // Prepare a select statement
            $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM login WHERE username = :username";
            
            if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                $stmt->bindParam(":username", $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                
                // Set parameters
                $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                
                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
                        if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            $id              = $row["id"];
                            $username        = $row["username"];
                            $hashed_password = $row["password"];
                            $options = ['cost' => 12];
                            if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                                // Password is correct, so start a new session
                                if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
                                    startSession(0, '/', 'example.com', true, true);
                                }
                                // Check if the hash needs to be created again. 
                                    if (password_needs_rehash($hashed_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options))
                                    {
                                      $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
                                      
                                      /* Update the password hash on the database. */
                                      $query = 'UPDATE login SET password = :passwd WHERE id = :id';
                                      $values = [':passwd' => $hash, ':id' => $id];
                                      try
                                      {
                                        $res = $pdo->prepare($query);
                                        $res->execute($values);
                                      }
                                      catch (PDOException $e)
                                      {
                                        /* Query error. */
                                        echo 'Query error.';
                                        die();
                                      }
                                    }
                                // Store data in session variables
                                $_SESSION["loggedin"]      = true;
                                $_SESSION["id"]            = $id;
                                $_SESSION["username"]      = $username;
                                $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
                                $_SESSION["twofactory"]    = false;
                                // Redirect user to welcome page
                                session_regenerate_id(true);
                                $url = $_POST["url"];
                                if (!empty($url)) {
                                    header("location: https://example.com/" . $url);
                                } else {
                                    header("location: https://example.com/admin/index.php");
                                }
                            } else {
                                // Password is not valid, display a generic error message
                                $login_err = "Wrong name or password.";
                                //error_log("Wrong pass/username " . $ipadress . " URL: " . $actual_link, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Username doesn't exist, display a generic error message
                        $login_err = "Wrong name or password.";
                        error_log("Wrong pass/username! IP: " . $ipadress . " URL: " . $actual_link, 0);
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Error occured try again later.";
                }
                
                // Close statement
                unset($stmt);
            }
        }
```

That's how user can log-in to admin.

And in all other files (what I want to secure) I included (to top of the file) a **sessioncheck.php** named file and check out if the SESSION is set or not.

**sessioncheck.php**

```
  if (!isset($_SESSION))
  {
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'example.com', true, true);
    session_start();
  }

$url = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true || empty($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("location: https://example.com/admin/config/login.php?url=".$url);
    exit;
}

If the last activity more then 1800 sec
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    header("location: https://example.com/admin/config/login.php?url=".$url);
    exit;
}

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

So my question is that if I request a file with ajax which have in the top included the sessioncheck.php file then it's enough or I need to improve something with verification (session check?) Maybe I need to POST token with ajax and verify that also?

What do you think? **What I need to improve to make my site more secure?**

Comment: For the server, all requests are the same. ajax requests are no different from any other requests. So it's not clear what your concern is.

Comment: If you don't check the user auth in a file, then obviously, this file is not protected

Comment: So if I request a file with ajax then is it the same as if I opened it from a browser? Is there no difference in security? (I mean in case if I check the user auth in file)

Comment: there is no difference at all. in security, processing, response, whatever.

Comment: You can add a CSRF token for all post/put/delete requests. If you use ajax for all requests, you can add an Authorization beare header with a token (random or jwt). For that, on server side, you have to save it in the session to compare with the header received. On client side, save it in the local store and not in session. Content-Security-Policy is very important too and others security headers